# Android Studio - Device Offline

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a small issue with Android Studio. Whenever I put my phone into either of the front two USB ports, it shows my device as "Offline". If I use any of the back USB ports, it recognises the device perfectly fine.

I can charge and browse my phone fine from the front two USB ports. I have tried resetting ADB, and installing/updating Samsung USB drivers. I have tried enabling and disabling USB debugging - but no luck.

It really can't be an issue with the phone or with Android Studio, as in the back USB ports it works fine - surely it has to be an issue with the front USB port?

Anybody have any ideas on how I could solve this? (Other than just using the back ones!)

Comment: My problem is with USB 3 ports. on USB 2 ports is fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. I have 4 USB 3.0 ports on the computer and 2 USB 2.0 on the keyboard. Nexus 5 can be plugged and recognized on all of them while Samsung Galaxy S4 is not recognized on one of the keyboard ports and one of the PC ports. In my case it is the device I guess. You can try with another device to see.

Comment: Thanks - I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4, maybe it's a bug wth that device. I have a mini on hand, I will try it with that!

Comment: I think you have the right answer - both S4's I have tried did not work, don't have any more devices to test - but I bet that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- Go to tools/enable **adb** integration and **uncheck** it.
- now check it and run again. Next time, android studio will restart **adb** and it may find your device.